# Spring Integration TCP connection factory SSL - Use java keystore

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

**Update** Fixed in [Spring Integration 2.2.1](http://www.springsource.org/node/3793)

I have a `tcp-connection-factory`

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="tranServer" type="client" host="127.0.0.1" port="1234"
    single-use="true" ssl-context-support="sslContext" />

<bean id="sslContext" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.support.DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport">
    <constructor-arg value="client.ks" />
    <constructor-arg value="client.truststore.ks" />
    <constructor-arg value="secret" />
    <constructor-arg value="secret" />
</bean>
```

And I want to use the default java keystore for the SSL context as part of the install process is to load the SSL cert into it.  How do I specify the default keystore and truststore passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** Fixed in [Spring Integration 2.2.1](http://www.springsource.org/node/3793)

Essentially the problem is that `DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport` loads the keystore and truststore from a `ClassPathResource` in the method `getSSLContext()`

```
ks.load(new FileInputStream(new ClassPathResource(keyStore).getFile()), keyStorePassword);
ts.load(new FileInputStream(new ClassPathResource(trustStore).getFile()), trustStorePassword);
```

I created my own `FileTcpSSLContextSupport` class which removes the `ClassPathResource`.

```
ks.load(new FileInputStream(keyStore), keyStorePassword);
ts.load(new FileInputStream(trustStore), trustStorePassword);
```

Then I create the bean with

```
<bean id="sslContext" class="com.liquidtelecoms.tillintegration.FileTcpSSLContextSupport">
    <constructor-arg value="${java.home}/lib/security/cacerts" />
    <constructor-arg value="${java.home}/lib/security/cacerts" />
    <constructor-arg value="changeit" />
    <constructor-arg value="changeit" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that problem recently; I have an open Pull Request that should be merged shortly: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration/pull/697